# People Attending Public Event + access token

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is there a way, for example, to show the faces of 5 people attending a public event?

Thank you

Comment: Do you control / manage the public event, or is it someone else's event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all attending lists are public

You can call http://graph.facebook.com/eventid/attending   then get the user details from there

Comment: Thanks, however you need an access token - and the documentation is pretty poor on facebook as to how you do that :/

Comment: You can either use a user's access token (?access_token=...) or the application's access token. For public events you can use either. For private events you need the user's access token. 

Note that at the moment the application access token doesn't work due to a bug